# Would like to clone private repo to local computer. (first time using command line git.)

Tags: git, github, repository, fedora

I would like to clone a private already existing repo to my local server. I've tried a series of commands to no avail.

```
[user@BC-01 gitTEST]$ git clone https://github.com/*****/Clinical.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dir/gitTEST/Clinical/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/*****/Clinical.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

[user@BC-01 gitTEST]$ git clone https://user:pwrdgit@github.com/*****/Clinical.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dir/gitTEST/Clinical/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://user:pwrdgit@github.com/*****/Clinical.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

[user@BC-01 gitTEST]$ git clone user@github.com:*****/Clinical.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dir/gitTEST/Clinical/.git/
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.130' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I get this private repo cloned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using SSH key authentication, so you do not need to type in your login and password everytime you connect to GitHub. First follow the documentation to [setup SSH authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

Then use the clone command with SSH link to your repo and it should work.

```
[user@BC-01 gitTEST]$ git clone git@github.com:<username>/Clinical.git
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to test this out. Also, can this technique be used to access any remote server?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a clone of the master branch. How can I get a clone of the other branches?

Comment: You can connect to any remote that supports SSH and has RSA key authentication enabled. To clone a different branch you can either use option -b branchName, or just check out that branch after you clone using git checkout branchName.